# Complete the equality

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Complete the equality to make it true:

```
1 1 1 1 = 5
```

- You can add any math operation or symbol to the left side.
- You cannot change right side nor the `=` (adding a previous `<` or `>` is considered changing it).
- You can't add any number. Not even implicitly: i.e. `√x` is `x0.5` so that would be adding numbers.
- You can't combine the `1`s (not for integers like `11` and not for decimals like `1.1`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible answer:

> $(1+1+1)!-1 = 5$

because

> $ (1+1+1)!-1= 3!-1 = 6-1 = 5$

Comment: I read that ! as not... but it's not D:

Comment: Is this a common notation?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

> $( 1 / .1 ) / ( 1 + 1 ) = 5$

And with only three $1$s on the left-hand side:

> $1 / (.1 + .1) = 5$

Comment: *You can't add any number. Not even implicit.* I think this implies a `0` before the dot.

Comment: @RomanGräf Don't see how that implies a 0, but if you're going to stretch it that far you could say factorials implicitly imply $1..n - 1$

Comment: i would say that you normally write $0.1$ instead of $.1$. Most calculators mal let you write it as $.1$ but any math teacher would give you a bad mark on that. (Sorry for my english)

Comment: @RomanGräf saying *any* math teacher is quite a stretch as well!

Comment: You can't tell me your math teacher, (if you have any, if not take the last math teacher that you had) would let you write $.1$ for $0.1$?

Comment: I most certainly can!

Comment: The question is if your teacher would give you a good mark on that test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60634/discussion-between-paul-evans-and-roman-graf).

Comment: I gave the same answer to the guy that show me this puzzle but he also said that `.1` had an implicit `0`.

Comment: @Diego after a lengthy discussion on the matter with Roman found that amongst hard core mathematicians it's pretty much an open issue so would counter that it has to be explicitly stated one way or the other by the OP - please see link in that discussion

Comment: I don't argue the notation, I think it implies a zero (or even a ten if you write it like a fraction). However, I'll leave this discussion to those who know better.

Answer (score 3):

Using the set of operators found in typical programming languages (so no factorial, square root, etc.), it's possible to do this by inserting just one operator in each gap, plus parentheses to control precedence:

> `(1 << (1 + 1)) + 1 = 5`

And [here's a link verifying the result of the calculation using an actual programming language](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvREFDw1DBxkYBSGorGGpqgsn//wE).

This makes use of the following operation:

> The "left shift" operation `<<` multiplies its left argument by 2 to the power of its right argument. In this case, we're calculating $1 \times 2^{1+1}$, i.e. 4, then adding 1.

Comment: Clever. But that is not a math operation, it's a bitwise operator.

Comment: I think it's a matter of semantics whether bitwise operations are maths, right? They're certainly mathematical in the broader sense (and they've proven to be more useful than, say, factorials in practice).

Comment: Although I'm not sure if it's a math operation I was hoping this solution to come up. I really like it!

Answer (score 0):

Possibility:

> $1\times\left((1+1)^2 +1\right)= 5$

Because:

> $\begin{align}1 \times (2^2 + 1) &= 5\\ 1 \times (4 + 1) &= 5\\ 1 \times 5 &= 5\\ 5 &= 5 \end{align}$

Comment: Can you square things since you can square root them? Or does that count as adding a number

Comment: Actually it does count as adding a number

Comment: *Sadface* (btw you may want to show where you got this from, it's not original)

Comment: I haven't thought of that, but you're right. It was shown to me by some guy, I'll try to track de original source of it. Thanks!